# Using position arguments with starred tcolorbox environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, tcolorbox, paracol

The `{tcolorbox}*` environment is interpreting position arguments in a way I would not anticipate.

When I include the `*`, the placement is unexpected--`\begin{VocabBox}*[b]...` does not get placed at the nearest reasonable bottom position, but rather, awkwardly at the end of the document.

If I exclude the `*`, the placement for `\begin{VocabBox}[b]...` is as expected.

These two MWEs should demonstrate my meaning (I could not recreate the behavior I was seeing with `\documentclass[]{article}` and had to use the document class I'm actually working in, `\documentclass[]{svmono}`):

[ Example 1 ]

```
\documentclass[]{svmono}
%%%%%% personally included packages %%%%%%%
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%% definitions %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewTColorBox{VocabBox}{ s O{!htbp} }{%
  floatplacement={#2},
  IfBooleanTF={#1}{float*,width=\textwidth}{float},
  colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,% any tcolorbox options here
  }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}%
\begin{VocabBox}*[b]
\lipsum[2]
\end{VocabBox}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[ Example 2]

```
\documentclass[]{svmono}
%%%%%% personally included packages %%%%%%%
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%% definitions %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewTColorBox{VocabBox}{ s O{!htbp} }{%
  floatplacement={#2},
  IfBooleanTF={#1}{float*,width=\textwidth}{float},
  colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,% any tcolorbox options here
  }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}%
\begin{VocabBox}[b]
\lipsum[2]
\end{VocabBox}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

### Question:

Why does the position algorithm give bizarre results for `\begin{VocabBox}*[b]`, and can it be remedied without sidestepping the package?

### Package info:

tcolorbox: [CTAN Page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)
svmono: [Download svmono.zip (*S*pringer *V*erlag *Mono*graph class)](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/svmono.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-491898-0)

Comment: I think you meant to say `\begin{VocabBox*}` instead of `\begin{VocabBox}*`.  I don't seem to have the `svmono` class so I can't test it.

Comment: A tip for solvers to get that class file: `wget http://ftp.utia.cas.cz/pub/staff/studeny/monogr/svmono.cls`

Comment: The same happens for the `article` class.

Comment: The same happens for `figure` and `figure*` instead of `VocaBox` (using `article`). On my system, for both examples and `tcolorbox` **OR** `figure` all the floats are placed at the end of the document. So, it is not a `tcolorbox` issue. I guess, it has to do with `paracol` and how to specify floats for `paracol`. I'm not familiar with `paracol`. Maybe, somebody can help who is.

Comment: @PeterGrill The syntax is `\begin{VocabBox}*`

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I think your conclusion is right. I contacted the creator of `paracol`, and he linked me to this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wide_figures_in_two_column_documents It seems that the problem is more general, and you can't position wide floats easily in two-column environments.

Comment: @MackieMesser Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround for you. Let the float object flow into one column, calculate number of lines it takes and add `\enlargethispage` with negative value to the second column when dealing with `*[b]` and `\vspace*` when dealing with `*[t]`, the value is best when related to the `\baselineskip` dimension. It is not an automatic way, esp. when adding `\vspace*` inside the paragraph(s), but it might help a little.

To compute number of lines automatically is probably for another question of yours as the `VocabBox` environment as it is defined now in the TeX file is in the outer mode and cannot be computed directly via the `\setbox` command as we use it frequently in TeX typesetting.

I enclose a TeX file and a preview of the result. We can run lua-, xe- and pdflatex.

```
%! *latex mal-tcolorbox.tex
% The svmono.cls file is available via:
% wget http://ftp.utia.cas.cz/pub/staff/studeny/monogr/svmono.cls
\documentclass[]{svmono}
%%%%%% personally included packages %%%%%%%
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%%%%% definitions
\NewTColorBox{VocabBox}{ s O{!htbp} }{%
  floatplacement={#2},
  IfBooleanTF={#1}{float,width=\textwidth}{float},
  colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,% any tcolorbox options here
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}%
\begin{VocabBox}*[b]
  % *[b] <-- \enlargethispage; [b] is for one column
  % *[t] <-- \vspace*; [t] is for one column
\lipsum[2]
\end{VocabBox}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\enlargethispage{-11\baselineskip} % when using *[b]
%\vspace*{10\baselineskip} % when using *[t]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]